# What is the way to wrap ggplot call inside a function and pass function arguments to ggplot's aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Consider the minimal working example

```
library(tidyverse)

myplot <- function(df, x, y) {
  df |>
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point()
}

iris |>
  myplot(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
```

It raises `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Petal.Width' not found`. How do I delay the evaluation of `Petal.Width` and `Petal.Length` to `ggplot`?

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use curly-curly `{{` which replaces the old pattern of using bang-bang `!!` + `enquo`. For more info see 
[What is data-masking and why do I need {{?](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html) and [the ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#indirectly-referring-to-variables) for using `{{` in a `ggplot2` context:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myplot <- function(df, x, y) {
  df |>
    ggplot(aes({{ x }}, {{ y }})) +
    geom_point()
}

iris |>
  myplot(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**1) dot dot dot**  R's dot dot dot works here:

```
myplot <- function(df, ...) {
  df |>
    ggplot(aes(...)) +
    geom_point()
}

iris |>
  myplot(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
```

**2) aes_string** Another possibility is to use standard evaluation with `aes_string`.

```
myplot <- function(df, x, y) {
  df |>
    ggplot(aes_string(x, y)) +
    geom_point()
}

iris |>
  myplot("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")
```

**3) formula** A variation of (2) which also uses `aes_string` is to pass a formula. Use `all.vars` to extract the variable names.

```
myplot <- function(df, formula) {
  v <- all.vars(formula)
  df |>
    ggplot(aes_string(v[2], v[1])) +
    geom_point()
}

iris |>
  myplot(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width)
```

**4) plot/xyplot** plot (base R) and lattice::xyplot arguments are the same as (3) except for order giving trivial implementations.

```
library(lattice)

myplot <- function(df, formula) {
  plot(formula, df)
}

iris |>
  myplot(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width)


library(lattice)

myplot <- function(df, formula) {
  xyplot(formula, df)
}

iris |>
  myplot(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using non-standard evaluation
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/

```
library(tidyverse)

myplot <- function(df, x, y) {
  df |>
    ggplot(aes(!!x, !!y)) +
    geom_point()
}



iris |> 
  myplot(quo(Petal.Width), quo(Petal.Length))
```